# Azure cosmos DB Slow when having documents of size of about 30KB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We have an azure cosmos DB with the following characteristics:

1. About 2M documents.
2. Each document about 30KB.

When we query cosmos DB using the Java mongo API
(`org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:3.9.1`)

Retrieving 4000 documents using the shard key ( should be fastest to my understanding) it takes more than 2 minutes.

Is it the common?

should i expect to get these times from the API?

example code:

```
collection = <... init the collection>

final Bson filters = Filters.or(Filters.eq("shardKey", "key1"), Filters.eq("shardKey", "key2"));

long pre = System.currentTimeMillis();

logger.info("filter {}", filters);
List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
FindIterable<Document> iterator = collection.find(filters);
try (MongoCursor<Document> cursor = iterator.iterator()) {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document e = cursor.next();
        documents.add(e);
    }
}

logger.info("Got {}, time: {}", documents.size(), (System.currentTimeMillis() - pre));
```

It seems that the client retrieves the documents in batches of about 100 items.
Is there a way to increase the batch size?

When using the Azure portal, the interface in the portal paginates the call and retrieves only the first 100 documents and then you have to click "bring more" to get more documents. It seems that for the azure interface it also takes about 2 seconds to retrieve each batch

What are my options for making it work faster? 
Thanks

Comment: As far as I know you cannot increase the size with the mongo libraries because they have no knowledge of the request options that CosmosDB needs. Have you trying limiting this query to a single partition key and see how that works in terms of performance?

Comment: Using a single part key (shard key) did not make it faster,  We used the projection() method to get only part of the document, this indeed made the response faster. Since we use PojoCodecProvider we had to create a new entity class that will fit the "projected" documents that return from the API